# GPU is overheating

Tags: gpu, fan, overheating

Recently my GPU is overheating to 95° with fan running at 100% when gaming, I never had trouble before with this card.
The card is R9 290 with a aftermarket Icy gelid cooler, I tried blowing it out it wasn't really dusty however.
In MSI afterburner I monitor the temp it will be like 80° for 20 min but then in a couple of seconds it jumps to 95° and it'll start throttling down the clockspeed.
I reinstalled Windows because I thought maybe I had some malware or mining stuff, I had it once with a program (utorrent) but still no use.
Before I had the fan at like 70-ish percent and had good temps, oh and idle temp is still pretty okay.
Next thing probably is replacing thermal paste or do any of you have another suggestion?

Some extra info I use:
GPU: R9 290 Icy vision Gelid
CPU: i5 3570k
Mobo: Asrock p67 pro
Case: Corsair carbide 300r
Windows 10 pro
I tried several Radeon drivers, I have 2 games installed: Dark Souls 3 and Quantum Break with both games it overheats.
I observed my Fans and it spins at max speeds, in Taskmanager I see nothing out of the ordinary.
In afterburner when stopping the game it lowers temp and the mem/gpu speed to around 40 degrees.

Comment: There is a serious lack of information and troubleshooting here. Have you checked for Updates, Drivers for the GPU and the applications causing it?
 Have you looked at your services to see what's using your GPU?What Windows are you running? I will edit your Q with a list of info we need.

Comment: Check services as in W10 you can see what is using the most of a specific resource e.g. your GPU.  Have you also tried using https://www.piriform.com/speccy this will show you temps on everything and usage.

Answer (score 3):

First, ensure that you have not overclocked your card.  If you have (or aren't sure), set everything back to defaults and slowly work your way back upward, if you want to try overclocking, again.  Be sure to make a note of any changes you have made, recently, as this could be the cause of the problem.

If that doesn't work, you may have a problem with the thermal paste (or lack thereof) between the chip and heat sink.  Make sure you have some high-quality thermal paste that is still reasonably new (not dried out).  I like Arctic Silver, but there are other good brands out there. 
 Turn the machine off and let it cool down.  Remove the heat sink and carefully clean off all the existing thermal paste.  Apply a small amount of high-quality thermal paste in the center of the chip, put the heat sink into position, and press down gently.  Secure the heat sink with screws, clips, or whatever method it uses.  If you see thermal paste coming out the sides, you put too much on.  Remove it all and try again.  Make sure that no thermal paste touches any exposed circuits.  What you want is barely enough thermal paste to create a circle that extends to nearly the edge of the chip, but doesn't go over the edge.  Some people like to spread it with their finger to evenly cover the chip in a thin layer, and a good case can be made for that method, as well.  Make sure the fan on the heat sink is plugged into the correct place, so that its speed will be regulated properly.

You may need to do a firmware or driver upgrade or downgrade.  If the firmware on your card has a bug in it, that can result in incorrect temperature reporting, poor fan speed management, overheating as a result of inefficient algorithms, and other issues.  The same goes for drivers.  If you have recently upgraded your drivers or firmware, that could be the problem; try switching back to the version you were using before the problem started.  If you are not using the latest (stable) drivers/firmware, you might want to try upgrading to the new version.  Try fixing driver problems, first, though, since firmware changes can break your card if they go wrong.

It's possible that the fan has developed a problem.  Perhaps one of the blades got damaged, and isn't moving air properly.  Perhaps a bearing is worn out, causing too much friction, and reducing speed.  If you have any reason to suspect that the fan is on its last legs, replace it.

In rare cases, if a chip gets too hot, it can start to warp the metal of the heat sink, especially if heat is not being distributed to it, evenly (such as when thermal paste is not applied properly).  If this is the case, you may see a tiny bit of "waviness" on the heat sink when you pull it off; or you may not, since even a microscopic variance can cause problems with heat transfer.  If you suspect this to be the case, buy a new heat sink that gets good reviews for the card you're using (not just any card!), or use the stock heat sink that came with the card.  Unless you're overclocking, the stock heat sink is often quite good on most cards, and is guaranteed to fit properly--which is more important than any advanced features an after-market heat sink might have.

Finally, are you playing a new game or running a new program?  It could be that what you're doing, now, is just more GPU-intensive than what you were doing, before.  Newer games/graphics programs or more intense graphical settings in those games/programs will make your GPU work harder, increasing temperature.  If this becomes a problem, try reducing the settings.  If you find that you just can't play the new games or use the new programs that you want to, it might be time for a new video card.

Comment: I haven't OC'd any parts, I play the same game as before when it didn't overheat. The fans run at 2000 rpm constantly monitored in: 'Open Hardware Monitor' and the fan blades perfect, system requirements for Dark souls 3 is well below what I use. I've ordered a new thermal paste it will be in tomorrow and I'll see what it does. When I think of it only one thing changed recently in my setup I bought a new screen with freesync and it's 75hz. I put it back to my old monitor and it's the same though.

Comment: I wanted to ada picture where below the temp suddenly after a long normal-ish temp period while gaming it goes up in a short time https://ibb.co/dGOzV5

Comment: Hey I just wanted to give you a heads up, So I re-applied the thermal paste and now the temperature with Fan 100% is 60°c instead of 95°c gonna tweak my fan speed now, I must say I'm a happy camper! Thx for all your efforts! bye bye cya

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed!  Happy gaming!

Answer (score 0):

### My opinion...

If the fan works and there's no dust

- 80% probably the thermal compound.
- 15% Maybe the fans slowing
- 5% Maybe the chip is starting to age and... using power... worse...
  (and converting more to heat)

I would bet on the paste, and change it out.

buy some extra heat pads for the ram, and mind the screws under all labels (in fact just take all of, if any, stickers off first.