# GPU shutting down at 65-67c while playing games

Tags: motherboard, gpu

I am having a problem where my GPU would shut down at 65c while playing games and cpu stays at 50c during that period, rest all components doesn't heat either.. I have already replaced my psu via rma and got a brand new seasonic 520w 80 plus, replaced my ram, replaced my cpu heatsink , tried changing the thermal paste on gpu didn't help either.. the only component left to replace is motherboard and GPU but both components are out of warranty so I can only replace one of them, so I am not sure which is at fault here. I am assuming it's motherboard because I do have frequent freezes in bios and even in safe mode which makes me think problem is with Mobo, otherwise why would GPU shut down at 65 when limit is like 90.. any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Pc specs
FX 8320 3.5ghz 
GTX 970 Asus Strix 4gb
Mobo - Asus m5a97 r2.0
Ram - Corsair vengeance 4*2 dual memory 
Psu -Seasonic s1211 520w 80 plus bronze certified
Cpu cooler - Hyper 212x
Ssd - crucial ssd sata 3

Comment: Are you running the current firmware for the motherboard?  A 500 W PSU is more than enough for your system.

Comment: Yes I am on the latest bios version..I even got my motherboard repaired from the shop, they replaced some IC on it and charged me 27 dollars for it but that didn't fix the issue

Comment: My motherboard freezes in bios/safe mode etc, windows password screen and basically it freezes within every 5 mins of usage.. can a gpu cause pc to freeze? Or is this a motherboard issue and I should buy a new motherboard right away,, since this is not getting repaired?

Answer (score 0):

According to Referred from thanks to evga website says

https://www.evga.com/support/faq/FAQdetails.aspx?faqid=57289

> Generally, Graphics card temperatures typically range from 30°C to 40°C at idle and from 60°C to 85°C under load. Most high end video cards typically have a maximum temperature between 95°C-105°C, at which point the system will shut off to prevent damage.

**According to Referred from thanks to softlay  website says**  :

https://softlay.net/how-to/safe-normal-gpu-temp-gaming.html

> The average GPU temperature for gaming should remain between 65 degree Celsius to 75 degree Celsius. As for Nvidia GPU temp they have an average temperature around 70 to 85 degree Celsius according to Fullmark graphics card test.

**According to thanks to Photonboy answer in website tomshardware**

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

Reasons for overheating GPU:

1, Using of CPU and GPU is more than normally would.

2. The cooling fan of desktop and CPU/GPU is defective slow or not working or Clogged fan or broken fan
3. Heatpipe or other parts of cooler is not working or may be corrosion or damaged.
4. Dust in CPU/GPU Fan heatsink or FAN .
5. Thermal Paste may be dried
6. Airflow getting blocked in Laptop.
7. Power settings
8. Overclocking of CPU /GPU  or VGA or RAM
9. Wrong GPU Drivers
10. Overclocking

**Solutions modified According to My knowledge and referred text from the solutions provided in various site links**

**thanks to KryssNova in tomshardware**
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

**thanks to photonboy in tomshardware**
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

**SOLUTIONS**

1. Clean the dust in CPU GPU RAM through blower or clean with isopropyl with 99.9 alchohol
2. Remove heat sink Fans of CPU and GPU and put some thermal paste on the chip and processor
3. Remove and  Clean the heat sink of the CPU and GPU  and clean it with blower and isopropyle
4. Clean the Fans cooler pipes or cooling parts if any through air blower and if found dirty then use isopropyl
5. Check CPU/GPU is overclocked in BIOS or any other softwares
6. Check if CPU/GPU is not overused by any Games or any software in background while normal use and while playing games
7. Find a large heat sink or larger fans for GPU  if it can fit as per size (check cooler master  or ARCTIC  site they have many solutions)

https://www.pclaunches.com/best-gpu-cooler/

https://www.newegg.com/VGA-Cooling/SubCategory/ID-576

https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Computers-Accessories-Graphics-Card-Fans/zgbs/pc/3015421011

8. get a Cabinet case or CPU cooling fans
9. Check power option settings

   - check Power Options setting
   - If on High Performance
   - Power Options>Change Plan Settings>Change Advanced Power Settings>Processor Power Management check all the tabs,

     · Tab : Minimum Processor State
         set to "5%" on both
       dont run your CPU running at Max performance 
       at all times without reason use when needed

     · Tab : System Cooling Policy

     ```
      set to "Active" on both, 

      dont run your CPU to run without cooling.
     ```

     · Tab : Maximum Processor State

     ```
      set to "100%" on both
     ```

     · click "Apply".

     · heat sink for CPU and GPU is probably connected 
     together, it could be that the heat sums up 
     together.
   - 3D settings of Geforce Control Panel (install Graphic card softwares), then you want to try changing Power Managment Mode to "Adaptive".
10. VSYNC power heating options

    ```
        (1) Run FRAPS and the game

        (2) Turn off VSYNC

        (3) Tweak averaging at least 10% above the 
            target refresh (i.e. 66FPS)

        (4) Turn on VSYNC
    ```

> hope my answer will help you if any of the option work do tell me in
>   comment which one worked for you and if not fell free to ask more queries and if it worked do not forget to vote and accept my answer

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer.. I will try this and let you know, however most of things mentioned in article have already been done, but I will go through this once more, thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried all these possible steps and even changing the thermal paste on my GPU doesn't help, my GPU still crashes once it reaches 65-67c and only way to stop GPU from reaching such temps is by increasing fan speed, however, this doesn't always work.. changing thermal paste on gpu didn't help and replacing psu and ram didn't help either.. I think it's the motherboard but I am not sure and I don't have a spare board with me, because my motherboard freezes even in bios at times

Comment: @Gaurav Batra bro  if your motherboard  freezes in BIOS then try to clean motherboard and GPU with h ISP isopropyle after removing all heat sinks of north south bridges and even processor outside tray sometimes dust  is hidden there and hangs boards

Comment: @Gaurav Batra secondly if u don't have motherboard and graphic card in spare then either check the graphic card in  some friends motherboard or give motherboard and graphic card to some   renowned service center or preparing guyz  they have spare boards and cards to check.the problem and even they have diagnosis cards to test the board fault rest before giving to service center if you find dust is user chips then try proper cleaning chips with isopropyle with 99.9 alcohol  it worked many time to me

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help mate.. for now I have arranged a galax 1050ti and I will test that tomorrow in my pc to see if it solves freezing issue and if it doesn't solve the issue, then I am sure the motherboard is the problem, so I would replace the motherboard most probably because I don't know how to clean a board with propoyl alcohol , if you can give me some tips on how to remove bridge and clean board then that would be great.. however the people to whom I gave my motherboard to repair a month ago, I think they already did the cleaning

Comment: @Gaurav batra best of luck try another graphic card and your card on other board  and if mother problem then try to clean as the service center and other technicians are lazy in cleaning generally   you can see the video to how to clean but be careful NOT TO SCRUB with any metal as it may cut tracks just use TOOTHBRUSH WITH SOFT BRISTLES or  paper towel to clean it and use either contact cleaners or ISOPROPYL (spirit) with chemical to clean dust a video giving for your knowledge its on to you to try or not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07LRtyzSiXY

Comment: That's very nice of you mate.. I will watch the video and see if it solves the issue if graphics card doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @GauravBatra one things whats your old graphic card what you can do is find the cards original drivers from manufacturer website may be some update can help it and rest i am sharing links of  some videos for graphic card overheating problems may it can help you  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnmKbZl4nOY   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26y_6bnXNkc    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBj9u2binds   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O98z3oiRc_k

Comment: I have updated the bios on GPU and also have the most updated GPU drivers and that didn't help sadly

Comment: Hello.. I have an update. I have tried putting a new GTX 1050ti in my computer and I am still having the same problem. The computer is freezing after every 10 minutes even on idle or even while browsing web, installing software etc.. for now one thing is clear is that my GPU 970 is alright and nothing is wrong with it, problem is either with cpu or motherboard, I highly doubt that a cpu can go bad.To me it seems like it's motherboard issue.. please advice..

Comment: @GauravBatra Bro Check your GPU 970 on  some other board to confirm if it fine or not... for processor remove cpu fan and heat sink and check if its overheated by putting fingers on processor (if its heated then immediately switch off pc) or  your cabinet speaker playing some music.....then its Processor problem ....if not then .... problem is with your Motherboard then clean all motherboard ..before reparing go for cleaning see youtube.com/watch?v=07LRtyzSiXY ...if it works ok not then go for ...repairing the board with service they may find the problem...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply again.. I have already tested this gpu on other system and it works okay and infact I arranged a 1050ti galax model and it was freezing within 10 mins of usage too, which makes it clear problem is not with my GPU.. cpu works okay for 10 mins but it freezes computer later, which makes me thing problem is with Mobo. Also, I have already got this motherboard clean from people who repaired it and they cleaned it properly but I think they just cheated with me by charging me 2000 rupees and didn't replace anything on motherboard

Comment: I think I might buy new mobo now thanks for your help

Comment: @GauravBatra if its cleaned then okay  rs 2000 is a lotz u get new mono in 2500 to 3500  again go to those guyz and say its not working and they cheated you and don't pay them single penny and tell them to work cleaning or preparing charges hardly good s from 250 to 550  ...if chip is changed then to they will charge rs  800 upto max no one will charge so much as all know in 2000 new boards come

Comment: @GauravBatra I think ur board  is old  amd processor is am3+  socket  and ddr3 ram now new motherboards are in market and processor Fx8320  are outdated and will be absolute soon I think they will be hard availability  and now not manufactured  and u will get old stock from dealers if available still you can try at Nehru place Delhi or in ur city or amazon but  be careful for warranty  and compatibility of your Processor ram HDD and graphic cards and fits in ur cabinet before purchasing or think for all new upgrade if have a good budget to replace all... All the best

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and your reply seriously makes sense and I was thinking to get the motherboard for my FX 8320 from Nehru place as well.. first I found out a motherboard of Asus for 2000 rupees on Ali express but delivery time for Mobo was 12-21 days and I cant wait that long so I think I will be visiting Nehru place and get a new board from there.. thanks a lot for your response, even if my issue is not fixed I am glad to get a response from an experienced person as you are guiding me in right direction.

Comment: I have already saved a lot of money for my new pc from my job and I have a plan of building new pc, but the only reason I am not buying a pc right now is because my plan is to get 10th gen Intel processor and I am eagerly waiting for the launch of that..  I don't wanna buy ryzen or 9th gen Intel right now because I know I will regret it later, I think I will build a pc when 10th gen comes out as I have saved enough money and I will use my GTX 970 with 10th gen Intel till the time 3060 comes and then I will upgrade to 3060 once it comes out

Comment: Also, I have another update... From last 3 days my pc is working absolutely fine and I haven't seen a single freeze idk how but it's working perfectly fine and I can play all the games the only problem now is that my pc goes black screen once temps on gpu hit 65-67c, the thing which I mentioned in post originally. However, if I keep my GPU fan speed at 85 percent from msi afterburner then I see no crashes even after playing games for 7 hours continous and that's because when my fan speed of GPU is over 85 percent then temps doesn't exceed more than 60

Comment: Although I still can't understand why would a gpu shut down itself once it reaches 65-67c that threshold is too low because actual temp limit on Asus GPU is like 85c above. I have already replaced thermal paste on gpu and that didn't help. Is it possible it's the motherboard which can't handle the heat and shut down my GPU as soon it reaches 65c ?

Answer (score 0):

**" A New answer In continuation with previous answer on discussion in comments and further updates information and after testing by Gaurav Updates ( the questioner)"**

As update that other card is also hanging on same motherboard and latest update that your PC is working on increasing the speed of Fan and controlling the temperature below 60

Gaurav question why PC shutdown on below temprature of 60?

**Gaurav Batra**

The **Motherboards or electronics circuits** always **restarts on heat** in **old times** processors used to heat and boards used to hang or restarts  on less temperatures  and due to the same reasons many new motherboards now  **have sensors of temperature** and they automatically starts of heating to protect the device **from bursting burning**.

There are **many new Motherboards** which are specially made for **OVERCLOCKING and OVERHEATING** and their heating temperature  **chips** are configured and clubbed together to  work on more  particular heat level temperature . Secondly overclocked motherboards have special **cooling pipe COOPER heatsink pipes**  or **COOLING UNIT** or **WATER COOLING** to keep the chips cool and temperature cool.

Secondly there are many reason sometime **Power supplies SMPS** less current (**Power wattage**) to particular device on detecting  more temperature for device or chip. Some time some Processor or RAM or **electronic components** on  PSU or GPU  like **Capacitor Transistors IC's**  gets heated or gets triggered on Heat as every electronic components have metals or coils and every component have limit of working on particular temperature .

**In your case** your motherboard **Asus m5a97** is old and dont have **overclocking and overheating** protections and features and manufactured at the time of **lower old graphics cards** (512MB 1GB max of 2gB) and you are using **advanced  Graphic cards** on a lower end motherboard and i dont think your motherboard **supports OVERCLOCKING or overheating**

**Now solutions**

As **you want to purchase**  "10th gen comes out as I have saved enough money and I will use my GTX 970 with 10th gen Intel till the time 3060 comes and then I will upgrade to 3060 once it comes out" so i think before purchasing spending money on **old "motherboard for my FX 8320**" try **following solutions**  for time being and go  for full new  upgrade with 10th Intel generation.

1. some NVedia (**Nvidia Inspector/ Geforce Experience**) Asus or Gigbayte motherboard or Graphic cards have **softwares or options in BIOS** to  increase the limit of Overheating  you have to find that software and can try through that
2. As you have increased GPU /CPU fan speed you can  control **cooling through software** or increasing cooling through **Fans or water cooling** so the components get cooled when they heated at the earliest and your computer dont shutdown
3. Also try to increase cooling of Your **CPU processor fan** and **GPU processor fan** and make your processor cool through  **water cooling**
4. Instead of **msi afterburner**  change or Install Run **Nvidia Inspector** for GPU temperature and fan speed testing and configuring as your GPU is of NVidea
5. As reading other links founded that Power Supply  SMPS of PC should be  of **True power 600w to 1000w** so that  the GPU gets enough current power wattage while working and sometimes may stop  GPU or other parts to heat less on getting proper  wattage voltage and current
6. Googled and founded and sharing with your  some more links (for **your knowledge and future reference**) on the problems with many other people with GTX 970 GPU and other users experts suggested

**According to Referred tomshardware website link thanks to user wildCard999 who Says:-**

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/gtx-970-sytem-shut-down-while-gaming-at-80c.2608638/

> Max Temp for the GTX 970 4gb is 98C, I don't think the GPU temp is the issue. What temp is your CPU while gaming? Another thought is maybe there's an issue with your power supply?I suppose you could use **a program like GPU-Z** and record the max draw of your components and see if its pushing your PSU too hard leading to the shutdowns.
>
> http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications

**According to Referred  NVidea website link Thanks to Greybear user who says**

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/277310/gtx-970-shutting-down-at-65c/

> Two things to try.....  **Download the 391.35 driver**, same instructions as above, see if that changes the results.   Second one is harder....**Pull the card, take the card and driver| .REG files to another computer**. Install and see if the Problem transfers.  IF the problem transfers, then yes, the card is the problem, replace the card, then recheck the system.  The GPU itself could be the issue and causing problems with the CPU.

**read  the Last reply STEPS carefully of Greybear the same post of configuring power supply and downloading and reading some power and CPU temperature overlclocking**

> When did this start? How long have you had this Setup?.....................
>
> Download SPECCY. Install REBOOT
>
> Download this 387.92 driver
>   Download DDU (get the 17.0.7.5 or NEWER)
>
> Disable the Windows 10 Driver updating. download the DISABLE .REG files in Option 2 and 4Merge one of the DISABLE .REG files and REBOOT. Merge the other DISABLE .REG file and continue with the next step.
>
> Run Nvidia Inspector Bottom right - Show Overclocks  Fan SPEED control appears in the middle between the original DATA and the Overclocks
>
> Download and install  HWInfo64 
>   Download and install 3DMark (3DMark is a long > Download)

**other links to see for reference**

https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4rvdew/gtx_970_video_card_solution_pc_instant_shutdown/

https://forums.evga.com/GTX970-FTW-Is-it-a-GPU-overheat-or-do-I-need-bigger-Power-Supply-m2330004.aspx

https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/pc-with-gtx-970-shuts-down-when-playing-game.397302/

https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=255907.0

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201147/gtx-970-running-at-80c-playing-arma3-on-singleplayer

[GPU is overheating](https://superuser.com/questions/1223299/gpu-is-overheating)

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/gpu-overheating-need-solution.1300651/

https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/overheating-gpus-what-is-the-best-solution.112163/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_temperature

> If answer of any solution works and suits do tell me which one worked for you in comment   and if not worked then feel free to ask for any further  queries  and  if worked then dont forget to vote and accept the answer

Comment: Thank you for all the replies, but the thing is this same motherboard ran this 970 for 4 years with no issue and never shut down and even the power supply is of best quality of Seasonic and this same power supply also ran my PC perfectly for 4 years so why won't the same components be sufficient now? Also my motherboard might be old but I paid 8000 rupees for it back in 2015 and this mobo is not a low end one I guess and this motherboard is same board which ran perfectly with my 970 for 4 years, all problems started after a period of 4 years and nothing changed in PC.

Comment: I am going to try the increasing temp limit for my gpu because I think that can solve the issue, but unfortunately my motherboard has no options to increase temp limit of gpu to avoid it from shutting down. Do you know of any software which I can use to increase temp limit of gpu? Thanks again.

Comment: I was thinking to do water cooling on my 970 but are you use that my gpu is at fault and not the motherboard which can't handle the heat anymore because its old? because this same motherboard ran my 970 for 4 years at temps of 65-70c with no issues at all

Comment: Please stop posting multiple answer to questions. You can edit the original answer if you have updates or more information.

Answer (score 0):

**" Posting a New answer In continuation with previous answer on discussions and updations and after checking and trying user is asking certain information in comments and further updates information and after testing by Gaurav Updates ( the questioner)"**

**Gaurav Batra**

> **As per your first comments** :-  but the thing is this same motherboard ran this 970 for 4 years with no issue and never shut down and even the power supply is of best quality of Seasonic because this **same motherboard ran my 970 for 4 years at temps of 65-70c** with no issues at all

As you are told me that you are  using **motherboard and same graphic card with all same parts** from  last  4 years and it was working fine means not shutting down at a **temprature of 65C to 70C** and graphics card.

But previously commented **"I have tried putting a new GTX 1050ti in my computer and I am still having the same problem."**  so i told you that may be **motherboard have problem** but there may be other problems factors reasons for  shutting down also may be driver software or other parts heatings

1. then as per idea  my thoughts either your **GPU or CPU or RAM or chips** somewhere in motherboard or Graphic card or some thing is **overheating** by time or dust or carbon in parts...you should check or **compare temperature** through **softwares** listed below of all components (CPU RAM CHIPS GPU) previously and now and find which part is more heating now it may be shutting down due to GPU throttle limit or may be due to heat of some other parts
2. The **game you  playing**  or any **other  software** or any other  **Memory resident program** (antivirus or any softwares) or any software to may be  **CONFLICTING** restarting  or shutting down the PC  you should cross check system files malwares softwares AND CONFLICTS.
3. Sometime system shutdown is due to **HDD reading errors on particular sectors** so u should **scan defrag HDD  and  chkdsk**  also
4. try to find **new update GPU drivers** or **motherboard BIOs updates** or **GPU chips Updates** any other update for **chipset drivers updated** may be they are corrupted or giving some problems
5. Try to **change Game lower down or GPU settings of Frame rate** or **resolutions** or CPU RAM usage  or any other system setting which may solve your problems

> As per **your second comments** :- try the **increasing temp limit for my gpu** because I think that can solve the issue, but unfortunately my **motherboard has no options to increase temp limit** of gpu to avoid it from shutting down. Do you know of any software which I can use to increase temp limit of gpu?

**Now my views:-**

1. I know you are using graphic card **GPU GTX 970 chipset** but you did not mentioned and told  of **which Company** (MSI ASUS  NVedia) or any other company of your graphics card. Kindly mention in question  company of your devices then it will be easier to find and troubleshoot your problem .
2. Find **Default GPU The throttle temperature limit** set of  card of your specific Manufacturing company.
3. As **per my suggestions** GPU throttle temperature limit is set to **protect you GPU motherboard and CPU from being Damaged by overheating** or burning   its **not advisable** to **increase those limits** its better to make your **GPU CPU cool** by Fans Heat Sinks or **increasing  fan speeds** or  purchasing new  big  cabinet fans or  CPU or GPU fans or **water coiling**. Still you can **carefully  try to increase**  the **throttle limit  by  software** but try to keep it **low by  Default  and preferred throttle** limit of the company
4. I am below sharing below  links of software's by various  company without proper knowing  about  your Graphic car company and mother board company. Its advisable  only  use or You should try with the **software of the manufacturing** dont try 3rd party or  softwares of other companies with your card they may force but may damage your card

**According to Nvdeia website link says:-**

https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2752/~/nvidia-gpu-maximum-operating-temperature-and-overheating

> NVIDIA GPUs are designed to operate reliably up to their maximum specified operating temperature. This maximum temperature varies by GPU.  Refer to the nvidia.com **product page for individual GPU specifications.** If a GPU hits the maximum temperature, the driver will throttle down performance to attempt to bring temperature back underneath the maximum specification. If the GPU temperature continues to increase despite the performance throttling, the GPU will shutdown the system to prevent damage to the graphics card. Performance utilities such as **EVGA Precision or GPU-Z can be used to monitor temperature of NVIDIA GPUs**. If a GPU is hitting the maximum temperature, **improved system cooling via an added system fan** in the PC can help to reduce temperatures.

**3rd party Overclocking tools (not ADVISABLE)**

**if you overclock then be sure to have WATER COOLING AND  COOLERS OF FOR YOUR CPU GPUS RAMS**

https://www.avast.com/c-how-to-overclock-gpu

**EVGA Precision X1.**

https://www.evga.com/precisionx1/

> Introducing EVGA Precision X1. With a brand new layout, completely new codebase, new features and more, the new EVGA Precision X1 software is faster, easier and better than ever. When paired with an NVIDIA Turing graphics card, the new EVGA Precision X1 will unleash its full potential with a built in overclock scanner, adjustable frequency curve and RGB LED control.

**MSI AFTERBURNER**

https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner

The world’s most recognized and widely used graphics card overclocking utility which gives you full control of your graphics cards. It provides an incredibly detailed overview of your hardware and comes with some additional features such as customizing fan profiles, benchmarking and video recording. MSI Afterburner is available completely free of charge and can be used with graphics cards from all brands.

**Download ASUS GPUTweak II**

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/removal-of-gpu-thermal-limit.830552/

https://www.asus.com/us/site/graphics-cards/gpu-tweak-ii/

https://www.asus.com/event/vga/gpu-tweak-ii/

https://www.asus.com/supportonly/GPUTweak%20II/HelpDesk_Knowledge/

ASUS GPU Tweak II provides an intuitive interface to access serious functionalities, all right at your fingertips. And the best part is, you can access all that on-the-fly, even in-game ─ all with one click.
Enjoy your music and videos by clicking Silent Mode
Game for hours on with Gaming Mode as the default setting in ASUS graphics cards
Bench and play the most demanding games by clicking OC Mode to unlock maximum performance
Stream and record your gameplay on-the-fly with XSplit Gamecaster

**GEFORCE® EXPERIENCE™**

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/

Capture and share videos, screenshots, and livestreams with friends. Keep your drivers up to date and optimize your game settings. GeForce Experience™ lets you do it all, making it the super essential companion to your GeForce® graphics card.

**OPTIMIZE YOUR GAME SETTINGS**
GeForce Experience takes the hassle out of PC gaming by configuring your game’s graphics settings for you. Don’t know what texture filtering level to set in Overwatch? Not to worry. NVIDIA taps into the power of the NVIDIA cloud data center to test thousands of PC hardware configurations and find the best balance of performance and image quality. Then it automatically configures personalized graphics settings based on your PC’s GPU, CPU, and display.

**NVIDIA Inspector**

https://www.techpowerup.com/download/nvidia-inspector/

https://github.com/Orbmu2k/nvidiaProfileInspector/releases

NVIDIA Inspector is a utility to read all GPU relevant data from the NVIDIA driver. ... Also included is monitoring of GPU parameters like clocks, temperature and fan speed. Multi Display Power Saver lets you reduce power consumption of the NVIDIA card by picking a lower power-state for multi-display

NVIDIA Inspector is a utility to read all GPU relevant data from the NVIDIA driver. It also supports overclocking and changing driver settings, for example to enable SLI for unsupported games.

Also included is monitoring of GPU parameters like clocks, temperature and fan speed.

Multi Display Power Saver lets you reduce power consumption of the NVIDIA card by picking a lower power-state for multi-display configurations.

> if any of my **answer works and suits your problem** then do tell me in **comments for my knowledge and research** which one worked for you  and if not then feel free to ask **further clarification queries** regarding the answer **in comments** . If worked then dont forget to  **vote for my answers and accept the answer**.

Comment: Thank you again for all the replies but I have already tried everything that is mentioned in this post. The problem that I was having with 1050ti was the freezing issue and that was irrelevant of temperatures, the pc would just freeze in bios or on windows password screen within 10 minutes of starting the computer. However, the freezing issue with my pc is now solved and i have no idea how it got solved but I am no longer having freezes from past 1 week. The problem is now only with gpu temps which leads gpu to shut down at 65-67c while gaming but increasing fan speed solves the issue

Comment: Games can be now played for 7 hours continuously if I keep my fan speed of gpu to 85 percent because that keeps gpu under 60c so I no longer get shutdown, its just that I want to fix this problem permanently because from 4 years my Asus strix 970 was running on default fan speed and it never shut down earlier. For now I can use gpu at high fan speed so I am happy about it but I am getting a little worried because summer is approaching and in India its very hot during summer, if temps the same it is right now then cool otherwise I can have serious problems.

Comment: Btw my GPU is Asus Strix Gtx 970 OC edition.

Comment: @GauravBatra  good your freezing stopped and  GPU is working on increasing Fan speed...for summer to temp wait and watch and if prob arises then use water cooling and enjoy gaming in summer also with it.....

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help. I will do what you say and if I face more problems in summer, then I will try a new gpu once and see if even that crashes at 65-70c or not and that would confirm if my gpu is bad or something else.

Comment: Hi, I am back because my problem has appeared back again and the this time my GPU shut down at 59c again but this time I actually got an error which said display driver failed to start and it appeared exactly when my GPU reached closed to 60

Comment: @GauravBatra as u found error...it means your driver files were giving problems......uninstall drivers completer....clean registry through ccleaner....... Download fresh latest driver.... Install fresh latest drivers...and let it work on default settings...

Comment: @GauravBatra restart PC after new drivers and don't change any settings set if it  may works

Comment: I tried reinstalling drivers 4 months ago and that didn't help. This problem started 4 months ago and that was the first thing I tried. My problem is hardware related, it's not software related.. I have reinstalled drivers multiple times in this month and my problem still remains same and I am on latest Nvidia version and I ran ddu via safe mode before installing new version.

Comment: The only thing I can't yet decide is wether this problem is related to my GPU or motherboard because a gpu shutting down at 60c makes no sense and it never happened in last.. I am thinking it's the GPU which is bad so I guess the only option I have here is to arrange a 1060 from somewhere and see if that new card also shuts down at 60 or not. If it doesn't then it's the GPU which is bad and if it still shut down at 60 then we are sure it's the motherboard which is bad.. I will try to buy 1060 from website which has return and refund policy because I only need this for testing purpose..

Comment: @GauravBatra as per your previous comment you have already tried other Card 1050 which started every 10 min "Hello.. I have an update. I have tried putting a new GTX 1050ti in my computer and I am still having the same problem. The computer is freezing after every 10 minutes even on idle or even while browsing web, installing software etc.. for now one thing is clear is that my GPU 970 is alright and nothing is wrong with it, problem is either with cpu or motherboard, I highly doubt that a cpu can go bad.To me it seems like it's motherboard issue."

Comment: @GauravBatra you have tried drivers 4 months before ..sometimes there are problem of Hardware conflicts....software conflicts...other conflicts also in windows.....as you told that your GPU started in 59 C and it gave an error of display driver..." I actually got an error which said display driver failed to start and it appeared exactly when my GPU reached closed to 60"...the solution for conflicts are many simplest is install a dual boot windows and without any other software game installed... just  install drivers and test your cards software with GPU Benchmark softwares

Comment: @GauravBatra.. many times many games or software overwrites some DDL files or changes some setting in registry or files of GPU drives and they may also cause some error conflicts also...u can try a fresh windows in dual boot   with fresh latest drivers and instead of game try  to test heating  overheating and performance through some benchmarking software https://graphicscardhub.com/graphics-card-benchmarking-softwares/

Comment: Thanks for your response. however, I formatted my windows just one week ago thinking it will solve the problem and after format I also installed latest gpu drivers and that didn't help either. I have tried every possible thing with this gpu and I am sure the problem lies with hardware because if it was software related it would have solved after formatting my windows a week ago.

Comment: I can run benchmarks just like other games with no crash if I keep fan speed to 85 percent.. however, if I drop fan speed below 85 then unigine and all other benchmarks also crash and cause a black screen on my monitor.. The thing is I can keep playing games if I keep fan speed above 80 but problem is that day before yesterday pc crashed even at 80 percent fan speed as summer is approaching so it's getting pretty hot and I see an increase in temps by 1c on daily basis so I am now keeping fan speed at 90 to play games but I don't think this is gonna work in extreme summer

Comment: I have also tried to run ddu and install old version of Nvidia drivers which came back in 2015 and that didn't help either. basically this gpu will crash at 59c no matter what you do, formatting windows and changing driver is not helping as I have already done that multiple times

Comment: @Gauravbatra then try this GPU with other FRIENDS motherboards and see if it shutdown other boards at same temp if not  then its board problem  and if yes then GPU problem..... And for GPU the solution is FAN Speed increase or water Colling keeping temp below 55 somehow till upgrade or Intel Launch 10th generation CPU ..

Comment: Yes, thats my plan. I just want to run this gpu somehow till launch of 10th gen Intel processors. However, I have no way of testing this gpu on any other system but I can try to test a new gpu in my own system and see if it crashes at 59c or not and if same thing happens then it surely is my motherboard. I will try to arrange a second hand 1060 from somewhere, thanks a lot for your help again.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience you did well to change the psu, however, chances are you choose a model too low for your needs. If you're still in the return period I'd try a 700w + psu. As the psy ramps up it starts to draw more power. Overheating is always a suspect but as it is not the case here my next guess would be your psu.

Comment: He has a more than sufficient power supply. Using NewEgg's calculator, his specs only reach ~400W.

Comment: I was using the same power supply for 4 years with same specs and never had this issue, still out of curiosity I decided to change the psu and got a new one as replacement and that didn't solve the issue, which means problem lies somewhere else